# How to get groups and contact ids of WhatsApp using API?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm developing an Android app that creates a whitelist of over 400 contacts and groups of WhatsApp to send them a scheduled message. I found an API to send a message using WhatsApp by passing the message and the receipt contact (person or group), but I didn't find another API to get all group ids of WhatsApp.

How to retrieve all WhatsApp groups' ids, using Android Java?

Answer (score 1):

Now you cannot process any group functionalities using WhatsApp. They deprecated all group APIs from WhatsApp. You can see the official confirmation from the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/group/)

> *We are announcing the deprecation of Groups through the WhatsApp
> Business API. The Groups API node will stop accepting any new WhatsApp
> Business API client phone numbers on July 8, 2020, and end for all
> WhatsApp Business API client phone numbers on Oct 8, 2020. Please
> begin migrating calls using this endpoint to avoid any disruption. As
> always, please ensure you update to the latest version of the WhatsApp
> Business API client and view the changelog for details.*